# multiplying "across" in two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two numpy arrays of shape `(25, 2)`, and `(2,)`, one can easily multiply them across:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(2, 25)
b = np.random.rand(2)

(a.T * b).T  # ok, shape (2, 25)
```

I have a similar situation where `b` is of shape `(2, 4)`, and I'd like to get the same results as above for all "4" `b`. The following works,

```py
a = np.random.rand(25, 2)
b = np.random.rand(2, 4)

c = np.moveaxis([a * bb for bb in b.T], -1, 0)  # shape (2, 4, 25)
```

but I have a hunch that this is possible without `moveaxis`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [185]: a = np.random.rand(2, 25)
     ...: b = np.random.rand(2)
```

The multiplication is possible with `broadcasting`:

```
In [186]: a.shape
Out[186]: (2, 25)
In [187]: a.T.shape
Out[187]: (25, 2)
In [189]: (a.T*b).shape
Out[189]: (25, 2)
```

(25,2) * (2,) => (25,2) * (1,2) => (25,2).  The transpose is a `moveaxis`, changing the result to (2,25)

In your second case.

```
In [191]: c = np.moveaxis([a * bb for bb in b.T], -1, 0)
In [192]: c.shape
Out[192]: (2, 4, 25)
In [193]: np.array([a * bb for bb in b.T]).shape
Out[193]: (4, 25, 2)
```

`b.T` is (4,2), so `bb` is (2,); with the (25,2) `a`, produces (25,2) as above.  add in the (4,) iteration.

(25,1,2) * (1,4,2) => (25,4,2), which can be transposed to (2,4,25)

```
In [195]: (a[:,None]*b.T).shape
Out[195]: (25, 4, 2)
In [196]: np.allclose((a[:,None]*b.T).T,c)
Out[196]: True
```

(2,4,1) * (2,1,25) => (2,4,25)

```
In [197]: (b[:,:,None] * a.T[:,None]).shape
Out[197]: (2, 4, 25)
In [198]: np.allclose((b[:,:,None] * a.T[:,None]),c)
Out[198]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with `numpy.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->jki', a, b)
```

Check results are the same:

```
(np.einsum('ij,jk->jki', a, b) == c).all()
True
```